# How to reject a cloudlet/tuple (request) in the cloudsim/ifogsim simulator?

Tags: request, tuples, cloud, iot, cloudsim

How can I reject a request (tuple) created by the sensor in ifogsim if it fails to meet the constraints and ensure that it is not sent to any destination within the network? Specifically, in the class sensor, each tuple must have a destination, but I need to find a solution for rejecting any requests that do not meet the specified constraints.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a couple of ways to do it:

1. While transmitting the tuple, you can get the destination or gateway device id. Use this id to get the device from the device list in the application class. Check the resource constraints of the device. OR
2. Create a custom Fog event to reject the tuple. Now, when you receive the tuple in the Fog device and find that it doesn't meet the constraint, don't process it and send it to the custom rejection event.